# SAS combining a variable of multiple observations into a single observation

Tags: sas

In SAS, I want to combien the variable `city` of each `county`,
here is my data:

```
county       city
 USA          LA
 USA       New York
France       Paris
France       Nice
```

And I want to create a new variable `Allcity` which contains all the city of each county:

```
county         Allcity
 USA          LA, New York
France       Paris, Nice
```

I only know how to combine two variables by using `city||', '||city`, but I don't know how to combien multiple observarions into a single ovservation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data have;
    infile datalines delimiter=',';
    input Country $ City $;
    datalines;
USA,LA
USA,New York
France,Paris
France,Nice
;
run;
```

The following code should help you:

```
proc sort data=have;
    by country city;
run;

data want (drop=city);
    do until (last.country);
        set have;
        by country;
        length allcity $100;
        allcity=catx(', ',allcity,city);
    end;
run;
```